# postgres 9.6 can find utility: pg_recvlogical

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm trying to learn postgres logical decoding. Their documentation says a tool 'pg_recvlogical' is included with the distribution. I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to install the `postgresql96-contrib` package.

Comment: Ugh. I don't know who decided to put it in contrib, that's not really where it belongs.

Comment: it was in postgresql96-contrib. Thanks. that was very difficult to find in documentation